# Visual studio 2022 is not remembering last opened files

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio 2022 by default opens files which are opened days ago not the last opened files when solution is loaded.

Also can't find .suo file in .vs folder.  To check if after removing this file i'll get the files

Comment: Try deleting the .vs folder. Maybe it's contents are somewhat corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because of two version files being in .vs folder. I deleted `.suo` file of older version and issue resolved.

Link for anyone wandering where to find `.suo` file

https://youtu.be/fDFcIKj0acI

Answer (score 1):

Double-check these settings:

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Reopen documents on solution load`

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Restore Solution Explorer project hierarchy state on solution load`

Comment: both should be checked right? If yes then they are!

Comment: @VishakhaSuthar Weird, (I have mine unchecked for faster loading), then all I can suggest is @PMF 's advice and delete the `.vs` folder and see if that does anything.

Comment: thanks, This was happening because of two version files being in .vs folder. I deleted `.suo` file of older version and issue resolved.